# Writing a Python script for reading an XLSX file or a DOCX file without activating macros

Tags: python, pandas, macros, python-docx, docx2txt

I have to open some XLSX and DOCX files via Python but I do not want to activate the macros. Do I have to write any code in order to prevent activating macros? I'm planing to use pandas.read_xlsx, python-docx and docx2txt.